# SQL add extra column to the table with calculated percentage value

Tags: sql

I have a table called `wp_affiliate_wp_referrals`.

I have next table now (SQL for creating test data and table):

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_affiliate_wp_referrals` (
  `referral_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `affiliate_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `visit_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `status` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `amount` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `currency` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `custom` longtext NOT NULL,
  `context` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `campaign` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `reference` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `products` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `payout_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `total_usd` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `wp_affiliate_wp_referrals` (`referral_id`, `affiliate_id`, `visit_id`, `description`, `status`, `amount`, `currency`, `custom`, `context`, `campaign`, `reference`, `products`, `payout_id`, `date`, `total_usd`) VALUES
(9, 17, 0,  'test_plan', 'rejected',  '17', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-06-21 15:51:18', 19.5),
(10, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '17', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-06-22 18:37:57', 19.5),
(11, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '17', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-06-23 00:45:55', 19.5),
(12, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '17', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-06-23 06:26:54', 19.5),
(37, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-07-21 16:56:06', 39),
(40, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-07-22 19:39:25', 39),
(41, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-07-23 07:29:19', 39),
(44, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-07-25 19:33:47', 39),
(48, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-07-28 18:56:40', 39),
(50, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-07-30 11:02:11', 39),
(59, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-08-06 02:28:05', 39),
(61, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-08-07 00:44:52', 39),
(63, 17, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-08-11 18:37:05', 39),

(65, 20, 0, 'test_plan', 'accepted', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-08-07 00:44:53', 39),
(67, 20, 0, 'test_plan', 'rejected', '24', 'USD', '', '', '', 'test-hash', '', 0, '2021-08-11 18:37:06', 39);

ALTER TABLE `wp_affiliate_wp_referrals`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`referral_id`),
  ADD KEY `affiliate_id` (`affiliate_id`);

ALTER TABLE `wp_affiliate_wp_referrals`
  MODIFY `referral_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=818;
```

I want to add 2 columns to the right side of the table:

1. First one is 'total' and id should count all referrals (all rows in this table) for
   each affiliate_id (including rejected, accepted etc descriptions). In this example affiliate with id 17 should have value 13 in 'total' column, because it has 13 referrals in db (13 rows for this affiliate_id).
2. Second one is 'rejected_percentage' and it should calculate % of rejected referrals for each affiliate_id. Formula is: rejected_count / total. So I need to calculate rejected referrals and divide them on previously calculated total number.

I don't know how to implement this in SQL-only, without PHP ( I use php in project ), because of the limitations of the plugin I am trying to extend. Any advanced SQL users here? Would appreciate any help or advices

Comment: are you know about Computed Column in SQL ? A computed column in SQL Server is a virtual column that computes its values from an expression. We can use a constant value, function, value derived from other columns, non-computed column name, or their combinations.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16  google